# Including numbers in linux rename command with variables

Tags: linux, rename

I'm trying to rename several files using the rename but I'm having trouble including numbers with the variable (if that's what it's called in this situation) portion.

I'm trying to rename `abc1d02.xxx` to `abc01d02.xxx`, adding the extra 0 between the c and 1.

When I try this:

```
rename -n -v 's/(.{3}).(.{3})(\.xxx)/$101$2$3/' *.xxx
```

It is trying to use variable `$101` instead of `$1`, add the `01`, then `$2` and `$3`.  I haven't figured out how to break the 01 part out of the variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `rename` command comes in at least three - complete - different versions on Linux. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: I can't try this at the moment, but `${1}01${2}${3}` will probably work.

Comment: @indiv - That worked perfectly.  Thank you.